# How do I test that a property of a model attribute is not null in using JUnit and MockMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, hamcrest

In the JUnit test below I'm validating that a model attribute is present, has a particular type, and a particular attribute:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get(MY_URL))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(view().name(MY_VIEW_NAME))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("myForm", instanceOf(MyForm.class)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("myForm", hasProperty("myProp")));
}
```

How do I then test that that property is not null?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You can simply use org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty as follows:

```
hasProperty("myProp", notNullValue()))
```